# Assign Joomla article to a always open under a menu

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

Is it possible in Joomla 3 to create articles and category blog layout that will open articles from certain category under a certain menu.

**Explanation:**

1) I have a HOME page: www.example.com/

2) I have a Main Menu and a Menu Item - News: *www.example.com/news*
This menu item is a category blog layout with news title, short description and readmore buttons (clasical)

**PROBLEM:**

So, when user clicks one of the news - for example How to make soup

It redirects them to the link: *www.example.com/1-how-to-make-soup*

**And what I want is to open it under the menu like this:**

*www.example.com/news/how-to-make-soup*

Comment: This question is about Joomla specific implementation details, you may get a better result if you, try asking on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 2):

You have a category :news
you have a menu (category blog) that is linked to "news" category
you have also some articles in "news" category

now if you browse "news" menu you can see intro of articles, when you click on "read more" you will go to www.yoursite.com/news/article-name
unless that special article is linked to another menu somewhere else directly

because in Joomla the priority for making URLs is making menu for them